# JavaScript - Invoke Custom Protocol

Tags: javascript, custom-protocol

I created a custom protocol into the registry named `fdmyalbs`. Invoking this protocol executes a PowerShell script which, for the time being, logs into a pre-defined file the received string (command + arguments).

When using windows' File Explorer and entering into the address field the string `fdmyalbs:MyApp?data=sdfsdfsdfsfdsf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf`, the created file shows `fdmyalbs:MyApp?data=sdfsdfsdfsfdsf%20sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf` which is exactly the input except that a blank is replaced by `%20`.

This means that the custom protocol definition is correct and activates the script as expected.
Now, I'm trying to do the same from within a **vanilla** JavaScript function using the following code:

```
:
:
var l_Test_URL = 'fdmyalbs:MyApp?data=sdfsdfsdfsfdsf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf' ;
const fetchPromise = fetch(l_Test_URL);
  
  fetchPromise
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${response.status}`);
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data[0].name);
    });
:
:
```

This code triggers an error message which reads: `Fetch API cannot load fdmyalbs:MyApp?data=sdfsdfsdfsfdsf%20sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf. URL scheme "fdmyalbs" is not supported`.

My interpretation is that `fetch` is not suitable in this case. I'm looking for an alternative method (instead of fetch) that would do the job.

Comment: JavaScript on the client side (i.e. running in the browser)?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, yes. I should add that the application I'm development (JavaScript + HTML + CSS) also works without a Web Server. As such, you simply open the HTML file with a browser and it work without any issue. This feature is something I wish to preserve.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Dear @halfer, you might not remember, but we had few years ago a long discussion about these matters. Being polite is not something I would avoid for any reason.

Comment: I remember. The site policy [has not changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=thanks&searchOn=3) since that conversation. I suspect [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) is the canonical guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fetch API is inextricably linked to HTTP.  This means that your interpretation is correct... that you cannot use the Fetch API with your custom protocol handler.

As far as I know, the only think you can do with that custom protocol is to link to it.

```
<a href="fdmyalbs:MyApp?data=sdfsdfsdfsfdsf%20sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf">Launch App</a>
```

You can also call a click on that link programmatically...

```
document.querySelector('a').click();
```

This should prompt the user about launching your app.

Alternatives to the custom protocol handler include running a web server as part of your app.  Alternatively, you create a browser extension to push data back and forth between your app and your native app.

Comment: Thank you Brad for your suggestion. I must ask a question though: will this work when the input to the protocol will be an encoded JSON whose size could potentially exceed, say, 300KB?

Comment: Hello again Brad. I implemented something like you proposed BUT, as I feared in my previous comment, this solution behaves like a URL and hence its limit is way below my needs (if I send something whose length is, say, 1K, it works beautifully but it breaks as soon as it goes above 2K). Do you have any alternative suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: @FDavidov Yeah, unfortunately you'll need to set up communications between the page and your application then.  If your application can listen on a known local port and be a web server, then you can access it like any other API.  Perhaps the link launches the application with a sort of pre-shared key and then communicates with it via HTTP on `localhost`.