# How can I invoke Custom Protocol with large amount of data?

Tags: javascript, custom-protocol

I'm working on a project that requires activation of a program from Vanilla JavaScript. So far, and with the assistance of Brad, I [managed to have the invocation to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77443348/javascript-invoke-custom-protocol/77443408?noredirect=1#comment136536812_77443408).

Now, the problem is that the suggested method limits the size of the passed data to the maximal length of a URL (2K) while I need far more flexibility to the data length.

The application works both using a Web Server (I'm using VS-Code with the Live Server plug) as well as stand-alone, meaning, opening the HTML file with a browser, all the functionality works are required.

As such, the solution should also be such that no server side functionality is needed not any special library.

I'm aware that this might be tricky but I'm still having some hope.

Comment: Where does your website get this amount of data from? Access that source directly from your powershell script, and pass only the **[location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) / [identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)** of the data via the custom URL. After all, that's what these are all about.

Comment: Hi @Bergi. The Client (JavaScript) invokes the PowerShell script with an argument (sometimes a long string) and the script saves the contents into a local file. The opposite direction also is to be supported, meaning, the JavaScript sends a rather short string and the PowerShell returns a large text buffer. Not Server is involved in these transactions at all.

Comment: And where does the client get the string from that it sends? Also how does the PowerShell script "return" a text buffer to the JS client?

Comment: @Bergi, The string the client sends is an JSON array. PowerShell scripts can return strings without any problem. In fact, before embracing this approach, I tested this by having two PowerShell scripts, one invoked by the other which returns a long string and the invoking scripts prints on screen what I got from the invoked one. You just use the `return "this is a loooooooooonnnnngggg string"` as the last statement of the script. It works as a charm.

Comment: Well that might *print* the string on the screen, in the shell that would have opened, but it does not *return* the value to the javascript in the browser?

Comment: @Bergi, when I use script_1 to invoke script_2 as something like `$Tempo=script_2.ps1` and in the next statement echoing `$Tempo`, when the last command in script_2.ps1 is `return "blablabla"`, echoing `$Tempo` in script_1 prints on screen `blablabla`. This means that PowerShell does return strings. I just need to know how to capture this within the JavaScript (I assume it must either with the use of `await` or a `promise`). I just don't know how to phrase this construct properly.

Comment: How to capture this result is a totally different question that you probably should ask separately. But the short answer is: you can't. A custom protocol handler allows you to start a program, but there is not any sort of "return value"; just like opening a new browser tab with a different url does not have a return value - it just loads a page.

Comment: Really it sounds like your powershell application should just open a web server, so that your js can communicate via http with it.

Comment: Thank you @Bergifor your answer. I have, however, a work around. The script is to return a list of files in a folder, something that cannot be done with pure JavaScript. What I can do is to invoke the script to generate the list into a file (known name and location) and upload its contents upon completion of the script. For that, I need to phrase an asynchronous call. I'll try that and will share here if it works or not. Thanks again.